# Jquery dialog with different content

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using Jquery Dialog with ajax. I am trying to achieve pop up dialog once a button is clicked (ajax.always) and then replaced with another dialog once done (ajax.done).

I have the following code:

```
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen:     false, 
    modal:        true, 
    show:         "blind", 
    hide:         "explode",
    resizable:    false,
    draggable:    true,
    closeOnEscape:false,
    width:        180,
    height:       200,
    open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
  });

  $("#dialog2").dialog({
    autoOpen:     false, 
    modal:        true, 
    show:         "blind", 
    hide:         "explode",
    resizable:    false,
    draggable:    true,
    closeOnEscape:false,
    width:        180,
    height:       200,
    open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
  });

.....

    $.ajax({
      url: '****',
      type: 'POST',
      data: values,
    })

    .done(function() {

      $("#dialog").dialog("close");

      $("#dialog2").load('pages/success_page.php' , function() {
      $("#dialog2").dialog("open");

      setTimeout(function(){ $('#dialog2').dialog("close"); }, 3000);

      });

    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      $("#dialog").load('pages/loading_page.php' , function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");

      });
    });

  });
```

However, this solution doesn't work. Ideally, I am looking for solution in which .always will open dialog with loading.php page and .done will replace content of said dialog with success.php and then close after few seconds.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you

Comment: `.always` is called after the ajax has completed (regardless of success/error).  So too late. You're looking for global ajax event handlers: https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: You might also like to look at a less intrusive method for the success "popup" - specifically something like toastr which will popup a message and (optionally) close it after a specific time or let the user close it themselves: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

Answer (score 0):

so as [freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2181514/freedomn-m) suggested i have look into toastr and this has been amazing. much easie and cleaner code and it works perfectly. Thank you